# ui-router not working in cordova angular ios build

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova

I have a problem while loading views using ui-router in cordova ios build. I'm using cordova angular in my application. The ui-router working fine in android build but while i'm running the app using `cordova emulate ios` the views not getting loaded.

here is my code looks like,

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<title>Awesome material design app</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/ionic/css/ionicons.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ngPercentDisplay.css">
<script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script> 
<script src="lib/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script> 
<script src="node_modules/angular-animate/angular-animate.js">  </script> 
<script src="node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular-local-storage/dist/angular-local-storage.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-touch.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
<script src="js/controller.js"></script>
<script src="js/router.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="YourApp">
<div layout="column">

<ng-include src="'templates/partials/sidebar.html'" style="top:0px" ng-if ="lang =='ENGLISH'"></ng-include>
  <ng-include src="'templates/partials/sidebar-right.html'" style="top:0px" ng-if ="lang =='ARABIC'"></ng-include>
 <div ui-view></div>

 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

The router.js file looks like below

```
app.config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider','$compileProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider,$compileProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/signup');
 $stateProvider.state('signup', {
     url:'/signup',
     templateUrl: 'templates/sign-up.html',
     controller: 'signupCtrl'
 });
}]);
```

The index.js file looks like

```
var app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},
// Bind Event Listeners
//
// Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
// 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},
// deviceready Event Handler
//
// The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
// function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
},
// Update DOM on a Received Event
receivedEvent: function(id) {
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
}
};

app.initialize();
```

controller.js looks like below,

```
'use strict';

 var app = angular.module( 'YourApp', [ 'ngMaterial','ui.router']);

 app.controller('myCtrl',['$scope',function ($scope) {
  $scope.detail={};
  $scope.detail.name="MyApp";
  $scope.detail.desc="welcome to my app!";
 }]);
```

Please help me if any one knows about this issue. Thanks in advance.